# Kayin and Hevels Sisters

Tags: riddle

What where Kayin and Hevels Sisters names?

Comment: Is there a source that has this answer?

Answer (score 2):

Although I have as of yet to find their names, it is mentioned that Hevel's additional twin came back as a Gilgul as Tziporah the wife of Moshe Rabeinu.

Answer (score 2):

1.Kayin Twin:קלמאנא

2.Hevel Twin:בלבירא

Comment: See R'GG's comment on the question.

Comment: Hevel had 2 girls born with him. What was the name of the other one?

Comment: Who is R'GG and where can I see his comment/

Comment: R' Gershon Gold. I'm a subscriber to the "mesorah" listserv at aishdas.org and the custom there is to refer to everyone as R' (or R'n, IIRC, for women, but one hardly ever posts to the group. I think this custom may be borrowed from their more heavily populated "avodah" listserv, but I'm not on it, so am not sure. Anyway,) I kinda like that custom....

Comment: It's like the Lakewood BP Graphics Semicha - Move to Lakewood, automatically get listed as Rabbi.